# Error copying a record from one entity to another using Entity Framework and Automapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to move a record from one table into another matching (almost) table using EF5, MVC, and Automapper.
This code is what I am using:

In My Global Application_Start

```
//Create Map and manually map StatusCode to Status
            Mapper.CreateMap<InstitutionStaging, InstitutionStaging_Archive>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.Status,o =>o.MapFrom(src=>src.StatusCode));
```

In my Controller

```
 private MyContext db = new MyContext();

   Public ActionResult ArchiveMe(int id = 0){

  var institutionstaging = db.InstitutionStagings.Find(id);

        if (institutionstaging == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {  

            var institutionArchive = Mapper.Map<InstitutionStaging, InstitutionStaging_Archive>(institutionstaging);
            //Set Archive date to now.
            institutionArchive.ArchiveDate = DateTime.Now;
//Error happens on the next line
db.InstitutionStaging_Archives.Add(institutionArchive);

            db.InstitutionStagings.Remove(institutionstaging);
            db.Entry(institutionArchive).State = EntityState.Added;
            //Commit the changes
            var result = db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

When it hits the line marked *"Error happens here==>"* I get the following error message.

```
{"The entity type InstitutionStaging_Archive is not part of the model for the current context."}
```

The MyContext contains DbSets for both InstitutionStaging and InstitutionStaging_Archive.

Any idea what is happening?
TIA 
J

Comment: Whey are you calling the `Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>` method inside your controller action? That's so wrong. This method is supposed to setup the mapping between a source type and a destination type. This method should be called only **once** for the entire lifetime of your AppDomain, ideally in `Application_Start`. Inside your controller actions you should call the `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDest>` method to perform the actual mapping. I invite to go through the documentation of AutoMapper once again to better understand the fundamental concepts of this framework.

Comment: I appreciate your advice. I just started trying to use Automapper in the last hour so I haven't been able to go thru the full documentation. I have moved CreateMap to the Application_start.Thanks

Comment: Now I'm back to my original error as listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error isn't typically a problem with AutoMapper, but rather a problem with your Entity Framework model setup.

It can be because you are using the wrong connection string, or it can be because you don't have the model mapped correctly.

Since we don't know what your model is, what your database looks like, or how your mappings are.. can't help much beyond that.

To prove it to yourself, just comment out the automapper stuff and do it by hand, and I'm pretty sure you'll get the same error.

Comment: There was a small difference in the tables that I missed. I fixed the tables/Entities and all worked fine.